# SQL Server : With in Select in NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, with-statement

I Have problem with this code.
I have tree in my data base and i need to select all nodes except The Node and his children, grandchilder etc.
I done WITH query - it works. I can select all big family of The Node.
But when i try to do SELECT ... WHERE id NOT ID (and here is the big family) i have errors...

**CODE:**

```
Select * from TALBE 
where id NOT IN
(
    WITH TempTable 
    AS
    (
        SELECT ...
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ...
    )
    Select id from TempTable;
);
```

or another version

```
Select * from TALBE 
where id NOT IN
(
    select id from
    (
        WITH TempTable 
        AS
        (
            SELECT ...
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ...
        )
        Select id from TempTable
    )
);
```

In this code I need to have first 2 lines. Its not my decision - just must to have.

**Errors:**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

```
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
```

Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You can't nest a cte as a subselect. Just remove the cte, it isn't needed here.

Comment: AFAIK `WITH` must always be preceded with a `;` (or be the very first statement in your script of course) - like @SeanLange mentioned, don't try to nest your `WITH` into something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, you need to remove the CTE or move it to the beginning of you're query.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

```
WITH TempTable 
AS
(
     SELECT ...
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ...
)
Select * from TALBE 
where id NOT IN
(
    select id from TempTable
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. You should probably read the documentation about CTEs so you understand what they are and how they are used.

```
Select * from TALBE 
where id NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID from someTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID from SomeOtherTable
);
```

Now that it sounds like you want this as a recursive cte you will need to adjust this a little bit.

```
WITH TempTable 
AS
(
    SELECT ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ...
)

Select * from TALBE 
where id NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID from TempTable
);
```

Comment: This only handles two levels, not n levels, it is not recursive.

Comment: What you originally posted did not appear to be recursive either. If you need a recursive cte move that outside your query.

Answer (score 0):

The way this code is written, the CTE query will be run for every row you're testing since a CTE is not really a result set, but a statement. This is very likely to cause performance issues down the road. A better way would be to cache the results of your query in a table in memory and use them when doing your actual select, like so:

```
DECLARE @badIds TABLE
(
    Id INT NOT NULL --replace the INT with whatever type your Id column is
)

INSERT INTO @badIds
SELECT someId
FROM someTable
UNION ALL
SELECT someOtherId
FROM someOtherTable
...

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @badIds)
```